# How to write unittest cases for checking database connection with SQL server in Python?

Tags: python-unittest

I have just started using unittest in Python for writing test cases, I have a function that makes the connection with SQL server.

**sql_connection.py**

```
def getConnection():
    connection = pyodbc.connect("Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};"
            "Server="+appConfig['sql_server']['server']+";"
            "Database="+appConfig['sql_server']['database']+";"
            "UID="+appConfig['sql_server']['uid']+";"
            "PWD="+appConfig['sql_server']['password']+";"
            "Trusted_Connection=no;",
            )
    return connection
```

I have tried below test case for checking database connect or not.

**test_connection.py**

```
import pyodbc

getConnection1=getConnection()

class TestDatabseConnection(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_getConnection(self):
        try:
            db_connection = getConnection1.connection
        except pyodbc.Error as ex:
            sqlstate = ex.args[1]
            print(sqlstate)
            self.fail(
                "getConnection() raised pyodbc.OperationalError. " +
                "Connection to database failed. Detailed error message: " + sqlstate)
        self.assertIsNone(db_connection)
```

But still not able to get succeed.

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_getConnection (__main__.TestDatabseConnection)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_connection.py", line 23, in test_getConnection
    db_connection = getConnection1.connection
AttributeError: 'pyodbc.Connection' object has no attribute 'connection'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Please help me out in this.

Answer (score 0):

A unit test for your getConnection could look like below. I would suggest using a patch and mock from unittest.mock. With a unit test you are only interested in testing the functionality of getConnection and should "Mock" all other function calls within the function. If you want to test the full potential of pyodbc.connect then I would suggest a functional test that actually connects to the databse which would no longer be a unit test. For more information on patch and Mock checkout the docs. These are very powerful and make unit testing fun and easy! [unittest.mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html)

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock

import pyodbc

def getConnection():
    appConfig = {'sql_server': {'server':'', 'database':'', 'uid':'', 'password':''}}
    connection = pyodbc.connect("Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};"
            "Server="+appConfig['sql_server']['server']+";"
            "Database="+appConfig['sql_server']['database']+";"
            "UID="+appConfig['sql_server']['uid']+";"
            "PWD="+appConfig['sql_server']['password']+";"
            "Trusted_Connection=no;",
            )
    return connection


@patch('pyodbc_example.pyodbc')
class TestDatabseConnection(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_getConnection(self, pyodbc_mock):
        pyodbc_mock.connect.return_value = Mock()
        connection = getConnection()
        self.assertEqual(connection, pyodbc_mock.connect.return_value)
```